# Angular Maps - get id promise?

Tags: angularjs, ng-map

In a controller, i want to get the map (Google) on the page, set the map id to a variable, and then use that map id, other places in the same controller.

I have a snippet like this;

```
var map;
NgMap.getMap({ id: 'mainMap' }).then(function (evtMap) {
    map = evtMap;
});

// Bind products to map
vm.products.$promise.then(function (data) {
    angular.forEach(data, function (child) {
        // add markers to map
    });
});
```

But because NgMap takes a little time to load, it is not ready when the code below is ready, and therefore map is undefined.
How to i make sure, that the code below is only running, once we have valid data in map? So just like the promise i am using, i guess, but in a different way?

NgMap: https://ngmap.github.io/

Comment: PS: The code used to be within the NgMap.getMap({ id: 'mainMap' }).then(function (evtMap) { // .. my code here });, but i moved it out, as it was conflicting with some two-way binding

Answer (score 1):

Providing a callback function to the `.then` method allows you to run code only after the map has loaded, so simply only add your products to your map, after the map has loaded (i.e. move you code **inside** the `.then`:

```
NgMap.getMap({ id: 'mainMap' }).then(function (map) {

  // Bind products to map
  vm.products.$promise.then(function (data) {
      angular.forEach(data, function (child) {
          // add markers to map
      });
  });

});
```

Comment: As i wrote in my comment to my post, this is what i had earlier on, but had to move it out. The reason beeing, that the forEach within, is 2-way binded, and it is not working as long as it is within the getMap function. Therefore i wanted to move it out of there.

Comment: @brother You have no choice but to perform this action inside the `.then` (or called by some function that is executed inside the `.then` because, as you pointed at, the map is simply not ready until this time. You haven't given much information with "it conflicts with some two-way data binding" so I can only guess that after you add the markers to the map (after `angular.forEach(data....`) you should call `$apply()`

Comment: my problem is, that on page loa, a bunch of markers is aded to a map via the above code (inside the then). My problem was then, when i added a new product, it was not replecting on the map, ie. the new marker was not beeing added to the map. A page refresh would fix it, but obviosly that kind of defeats the purpose :) So my therory was, that the then function, was only being run on load, and therefore there was no '2 way binding' sort of speak.

Comment: You'll have to `$watch` you `products` for changes and update the map markers accordingly. Why did you expect changing your `products` would automatically update your map? That has to be handled by the `NgMap` module and if the `NgMap` module doesn't have a place where you can say - these are my markers, update them when this array/promise/whatever gets updated - then you have to do it yourself - by `$watch`-ing your variable and updating the map accordingly.

Comment: Hmm, yes, sounds logical when you say it like that ;) Would it be possible for a short example of how $watch could be implemented in my example?

Comment: Tried moving the entire forEach into a ng-repeat instead, in the view, like so: <ng-map id="mainMap">
 <marker ng-repeat="product in ctrl.products" position="{{product.x}}, {{product.y}}"></marker></ng-map>.

And then it was 2-way binded. So it must be something with the watch, as you also state. But how to setup it up, as the ng-repeat is not an option, since i have far to many config settings to fit into that.